# Use Foreign Key to access data on different database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a central database `Student` that all my other tables Foriegn Key to, which in turn Foreign Keys to various records in my `Courses` database.

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    FIRST_NAME  varchar(50),
    LAST_NAME varchar(50),
    OSIS number(10,0),
    OFCL varchar(5),
    GRADE number(4,0),
    COURSE_0 varchar(5),
    COURSE_1 varchar(5),
    COURSE_2 varchar(5),
    COURSE_3 varchar(5),
    COURSE_4 varchar(5),
    COURSE_5 varchar(5),
    COURSE_6 varchar(5),
    COURSE_7 varchar(5),
    COURSE_8 varchar(5),
    COURSE_9 varchar(5),
    COURSE_10 varchar(5),
    CONSTRAINT pk_student PRIMARY KEY (OSIS),
    CONSTRAINT course_0 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_0) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_1 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_1) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_2 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_2) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_3 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_3) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_4 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_4) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_5 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_5) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_6 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_6) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_7 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_7) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_8 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_8) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_9 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_9) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT course_10 FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_10) REFERENCES course(COURSE_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE course( 
    TITLE varchar(25), 
    COURSE_ID varchar(5), 
    PERID number(10,0), 
    OSIS number(10,0), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_teacher FOREIGN KEY (OSIS) REFERENCES teacher(OSIS), 
    CONSTRAINT pk_course PRIMARY KEY(COURSE_ID) 
)
```

I also have an `Absent` database that consists of Foreign Keys to the `Student` database.

```
CREATE TABLE absent( 
    OSIS number(10,0), 
    CONSTRAINT student_absent FOREIGN KEY (OSIS) REFERENCES student(OSIS) 
)
```

I'm looking for a way to access data on `Student` using Foreign Keys on `Absent`. For example, if I had an `OSIS` number `1234567890` on `Student` and `Absent`, I'd like to access data paired with `1234567890` on `Student` using the `1234567890`'s Foreign Key on `Absent`. I've found relatively little documentation on invoking Foreign Keys (only setting them up), so what steps should I take to invoke `Absent`'s Foreign Keys?

Comment: `invoking foreign keys`? You should start with `select` statements I guess...

Comment: What is the real question? How to simply join keys in a `select` query?

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys are constraints not program constructs. They prevent us inserting a record in `absence` which doesn't reference an existing record in `student`.

So all you need to do is join the tables:

```
select s.*
from student s
   join absence a
       on a.osis = s.osis
where a.osis = 124466 -- or whatever
```

---

Incidentally all those `course` columns are really ugly: you should normalize the data model and introduce an intersection table, say `student_course`, between the two tables